# Access Cordova plugins directly from ionic2 typescript components

Tags: cordova, angular, cordova-plugins, ionic2

I am creating new Ionic2 typescript application. Few of the required native access plugins are not available in ionic native till now(Routed device check plugin, Read SMS plugins etc). So i required to use cordova plugins directly with out intervention of ionic native class and injection formalities. your suggestions are appreciable. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing to stop you from using these plugins.
Just tell typescript that they exist like so:

```
declare var rootdetection:any;
```

If you want to be proficient about it, writing your typing(an interface with all the plugins functionality) for the plugin and add it to your project

Comment: please help me in this https://stackoverflow.com/q/44343585/3600674, getting same error