# Wrapper of cordova plugins in Ionic3

Tags: cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3, ionic-native

I want to use [cordova-plugin-wechat](https://github.com/xu-li/cordova-plugin-wechat) in ionic 3.
But I'm not sure how to use it.
There is [@ionic-native/alipay](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/alipay/) for [cordova-alipay-base](https://github.com/xueron/cordova-alipay-base).
I tried to make @ionic-native/wechat by following @ionic-native/alipay, but couldn't.
It's sure that @ionic-native plugins used typescript module wrapper, but can't read it with my type script level.
Please give me some advice.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532737/access-cordova-plugins-directly-from-ionic2-typescript-components same idea

Comment: thanks misha, but I get 'Wechat is undefined' error.

Comment: Are you testing on your phone?

Comment: No, I'm not. Let me test it on a phone.

Comment: I tested on phone, but app doesn't run.

Comment: See the error in the console of the phone then. I'll try to explain in general the situation. These @ionic-native packages are wrappers for the original static variables that are injected by cordova(only on phone) when you install the plugin. I only suggested you skip the wrappers and go directly towards the plugins